# Is this code Oauth 2.0 compatible?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook, oauth-2.0

Facebook announced that all apps must migrate to OAuth 2.0 by 1st of October 2011

> October 1, 2011    OAuth 2.0 Migration As we announced in May, all apps
>   must migrate to OAuth 2.0 for authentication and expect an encrypted
>   access token. The old SDKs, including the old JS SDK and old iOS SDK
>   will no longer work.

Read more here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/oauth2-https-migration/

Now I am pretty confused by all the different flows and versions. I have a simple authentication going on that looks basically like this (I stripped the un essential parts)

```
    ## setup ###

    $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=".$this->appid."&redirect_uri=".$myurl;
    header("Location: $url");
    exit();
```

and when the user returns...

```
    ## authentication check ##

    $code = isset($_GET["code"]) ? $_GET["code"] : false;
    if(!$code) {
        // user has not authenticated yet, lets return false so setup redirects him to facebook
        return false;
    }
    $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=".$this->appid."&redirect_uri=";
    $redirecturl = urlencode($redirecturl);     
    $url .= $redirecturl;
    $url .= "&client_secret=".$this->secret;
    $url .= "&code=".$code;
    $data = $this->get_data($url); // fetches content over https

    parse_str($data,$data);
    $token = $data['access_token'];
    $data = $this->get_data('https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token='.urlencode($token));
    $data = json_decode($data);

    $id = $data->id;

    if($id > 0) {

        // yeah authenticated!

    } else {
        // login failed
    }
```

Is this method ready for the compulsory migration?

Comment: oauth2 spec defenitly states, how should client authenticate to TokenEndpoint. More it says that response should be json. That is: partially it is not standard compliant.

Answer (score 0):

short answer... it is..................

Comment: TokenEndpoint implementation does not confirm OAUTH2 standard.
Doing a get with client_secret in URL is not the way standard demands. More, it is against security logic, that is carefully described in standard.

Comment: what can i say. you're right. i think i was referring to an unfinished standard at the time. its been 2 years after all...